# SQL/Dynamic SQL - Add column if it does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have the SQL query below:

```
create table #temp
(
Account varchar(5),
category varchar(6),
amount money
)

insert into #temp values ('A001', 'ABC-CO', 1000.00)
insert into #temp values ('A002', 'DEF-CR', 500.00)
insert into #temp values ('A002', 'GHI-PR', 800.00)
insert into #temp values ('A003', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into #temp values ('A004', 'ABC-PR', 1100.00)


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(c.category, '-PR',''),'- 
CO',''),'-CR',''))
    FROM #temp c
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Account, ' + @cols + ', (case when DEF is not NULL and GHI is not NULL then 1 
                                        when ABC is not NULL then 1
                                        else 0 end) as Outcome from 
    (
        select Account
            , amount
            , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(category, ''-PR'',''''),''-CO'',''''),''-CR'','''') as 
category
        from #temp 
   ) x
    pivot 
    (
         max(amount)
        for category in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table #temp
```

Which generates the below table:

```
 Account    ABC      DEF     GHI        Outcome
 A001       1000.00  NULL    NULL       1
 A002       NULL     500.00  800.00     1
 A003       NULL     700.00  NULL       0
 A004       1100.00  NULL    NULL       1
```

My issue is that the case statement is built off a known relationship where some of the columns do not appear in the query.

For example if I added to the case statement:

```
case when DEF is not NULL and JKL is not NULL then 1
```

The desired output is that since JKL doesn't exist, then  0.

Since JKL doesn't exist though, the query errors. How can I edit the code above to review table for column JKL, if it does not exist then add column JKL with NULL values, and then reference in case statement?

Comment: Yes, you would need for each column to be checked in system tables whether it exists in particular table or not and based on that add the condition to evaluate to false (0).

Comment: Hi Kamil, I came across that possibility, but am not sure how to implement.

Comment: It actually depends which RDBMS are you using. Answer will vary depending on it. Please edit your question and include a tag of database you are using. I assume this is SQL Server. Which version?

Comment: I believe I updated question correctly. Also, it's SQL Server, version 14.0.17289.0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the "columns" derive from the pivoted category values. Just insert dummy DEF, GHI, ABC categories for an account with NULL amount. Those null values will not affect the result and will generate the DEF, GHI, ABC columns if none of the accounts has those categories.

```
..........................
insert into #temp values ('A004', 'ABC-PR', 1100.00)


insert into #temp(Account, category, amount)
select a.Account, c.category, null
from
(
select top (1) Account from #temp
) as a 
cross join (values('DEF'), ('GHI'), ('ABC'), ('JKL')) AS c(category);

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
.........................
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it's unknown which column headers will be missing. For example ABC could be missing instead of JKL.

Comment: you only need to create dummy entries for the categories::columns that you explicitly reference in the query. 3 explicit columns appear in the case statement and these are DEF, GHI, ABC..and JKL and any other column you explicitly want to use....

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure how to implement your solution, but there are 300 combinations of headers that I need to reference in the case and I don't know how many or if any "JKLs" will appear.

Comment: added the JKL dummy category too. this will generate a "JKL column" in the pivoted "table"

Comment: thanks for your help. So I tested the approach and an issue is that it creates duplicate columns. So if the pivot created 'JKL' and then I cross join 'JKL', I get two columns with 'JKL'

Comment: insert the dummy categories before starting the dynamic column retrieval. (the insert into #temp..cross join... is before DECLARE @cols...)