# SQL Server - If columns not exist then create column

Tags: sql-server

I have an example table(#temp) like:

```
Account    ABC      DEF     GHI     
-----------------------------------
A001       1000.00  NULL    NULL    
A002       NULL     500.00  800.00  
A003       NULL     700.00  NULL    
A004       1100.00  NULL    NULL
```

The headers ABC, DEF, GHI are the result of a pivot. I'd like to:

```
select 
    *,
    case 
       when ABC is not NULL and JKL is not NULL 
          then 1 
          else 0 
    end as newColumn 
from 
    #temp
```

This errors out, because `JKL` doesn't exist. However, it can exist and has to be accounted for when it does. How can I edit my query statement to check if the columns ABC and JKL exist > if they do not exist then 0 value > if they do exist and either are null then 0 value > if they are both not null then 1 value in a newColumn.

Comment: columns are bound at compile time, so the only way I can suggest you do this is via dynamic SQL.

Comment: The fact that you have a table that doesn't have a defined definition seems odd. Why not just ensure you have the column `JKL`, even if it isn't needed?

Comment: @Larnu - I think one potential solution is to create a new column if the column doesn't exist. However, I'm not sure how to implement that route.

Comment: Your database design is flawed. You absolutely should not have this kind of problem. Which means you should read up on proper database design and change your database layout, instead of trying to work around this problem.

Comment: Agreed, but that lift is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using a temporary table, this is a bit ugly, but perhaps something like this would work:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM tempdb.sys.tables t
                    JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
               WHERE t.name LIKE N'#temp[_]%'
                 AND c.[name] = N'JKL')
    ALTER TABLE #Temp ADD JKL int;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(13);
--Need dynamic SQL, as the batch will fail still otherwise
SET @SQL = N'SELECT *,' + @CRLF + 
           N'CASE WHEN ABC IS NOT NULL AND JKL IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS newColumn' + @CRLF + 
           N'FROM #temp;'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If `JKL` should have a non-`NULL` value then use the following for the `ALTER`:

```
    ALTER TABLE #Temp ADD JKL int DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES;
```

Comment: The top section I was unable to run, but it did lead me to the below solution.

Comment: I see, I had written `dbo` here instead of `sys`, my bad. Fixed. (It's getting late here)

Comment: That works. Question: Why join tables t to columns c instead of just a simple search like: 
    SELECT [name] 
               FROM   tempdb.sys.columns 
               WHERE  [object_id] = Object_id(N'tempdb..#temp') 
                      AND [name] LIKE 'JKL'

Comment: Habit more than anything, @dcrowley01 .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete with:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1
    from tempdb.sys.tables t
        inner join tempdb.sys.columns c
        on t.object_id = c.object_id
    where t.Name like '%temp%' AND
        c.Name = 'JKL')
ALTER TABLE #temp ADD JKL int;

select * from #temp
```

Comment: What happened to the `CASE` expression you need?

Comment: @larna - Once the column is added, I can create a secondary temp table if necessary to include the case. I posted a more complicated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632295/sql-dynamic-sql-add-column-if-it-does-not-exist